# Does there exist Eulerian quadrangulations that are not 1- or 2-degenerate?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, eulerian-path

I am looking for Eulerian planar quadrangulations that are not 1- or 2-degenerate, but I cannot seem to find such graphs.

Note: a graph is Eulerian if and only if every vertex has an even degree. Clearly there exists such quadrangulations, for example, $K_{2,6}$ where the points in the partite set of $2$-points are placed on both sides of a line of the set with $6$ points. However, the case of creating a planar quadrangulation with each vertex having an even degree, and the quadrangulation also being $\ge 3$-degenerate, this becomes a lot more complicated. Are there any existing examples of such?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the blue vertices to find a subgraph (which is itself a quadrangulation!) that has minimum degree $3$.

[image: Eulerian Quadrangulation with degeneracy 3]

Comment: The removal of the degree 4 blue vertex does not give a quadrangulation unless you delete the other edge as well.

Comment: @polygonlink1 What do you mean "other edge"? If you remove all blue vertices (and, of course, edges incident with them), you get a cube graph $Q_3$.

Comment: Yes but $Q_3$ has vertices of odd degree.

Comment: Your question asks for an Eulerian Quadrangulation that has degeneracy at least 3. This graph is that - it has only even degree, and degeneracy 3 because of the induced cube. It seems that what you might *really* want to ask about is an Eulerian quadrangulation with minimum degree 3 - which is a different question entirely.